# How to check multiple conditions to be true or false using protractor ,so that it helps in validating input before click

Tags: node.js, protractor

Here is the code where i want to check for the value of inputs nick_name and the room_name before clicking the button(createRoom_btn).But i am not getting how to check for multiple conditions in single if statement using protractor.

```
var nick_name = element(by.model('user.vcard.nickname'));
var room_name = element(by.model('roomName'));
var createRoom_btn = element(by.tagName('button'));
describe('Protractor Demo App', function () {
    it('should click on create room button', function () {
        condition = function () {
            return [
                nick_name.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
                    return value.length > 0
                }),
                room_name.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
                    return value.length > 0
                })
            ];
        };
        browser.wait(condition, 8000, "Text is still not present").then(function (resp) {
        });
        //button click         
        browser.actions().mouseMove(createRoom_btn).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: "how to check for multiple conditions in single if statement"... I don't see any `if` statements anywhere in this code?  Also please reformat your code, very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `'and' ExpectedCondition` - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.and - to combine conditions. If you have a value that you are waiting for then use the `textToBePresentInElementValue ExpectedCondition` - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElementValue.

Else to check if value is entered, you can write a custom condition to check length.

```
var valuePresentNick = function() {
  return nick_name.getAttribute('value').then(function(txt) {
    return txt.length > 0;
  });
};
```

Create something similar for room name - `valuePresentRoom`

```
var condition = EC.and(valuePresentNick , valuePresentRoom);
browser.wait(condition, 5000);
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions